# How to resolve kube-proxy stuck in container creating state?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, rhel, cri-o

I am trying to join a ubuntu host to rhel kubernetes master.
Installed kubernetes version 1.24.3 and using crio runtime.
If i join a rhel vm to rhel kubernetes master. There is no issue.
But when i join the ubuntu to host to rhel kubernetes master. kube-proxy in kube-system is stuck in container creating state.

Describe the node and getting the following error:

> Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error
> creating pod sandbox with name
> "k8s_kube-proxy-s56kp_kube-system_(ID)": initializing source
> docker://registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6: pinging container registry
> registry.k8s.io: Get "https://registry.k8s.io/v2/": dial tcp (ip):443:
> i/o timeout

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution :

Proxy has to be set in `/etc/sysconfig/crio`:

```
HTTP_PROXY=<proxy>
HTTPS_PROXY=<proxy> 
NO_PROXY=<IPs>

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart crio
```